# How can I restrict the number of times a list item is selected with random.choice()

Tags: python, random

I have got a list like

```
L = ["bus", "bike"]
```

and I want to print randomly the items from the list

```
for i in range(10):
    print "Customer %d uses the %s" % (i, random.choice(L))
```

If I want, for instance, to print `"bus"` 6 times and `"bike"` 4 times, is there a way to do it in Python?

Comment: This is the beginning of Monte Carlo methods, which is a rich topic and the margin here is too small ;)  In general, you seek the transformation from discrete uniform distribution, or from the continuous uniform distribution on unit interval[1], to your target distribution. There are many ways to do this, e.g. by direct transformation, or rejection method, or mixture, or Markov chain, etc. [1] actually the former can be generated from the latter, so mathematically you only need the continuous uniform one as your starting point. Once you grasp how to do this, you've gained a big step forward.

Answer (score 3):

Create a list with your desired distribution and shuffle it:

```
l = 6*[0] + 4*[1]
random.shuffle(l)
for i in l:
    print(L[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

To expand my comment slightly (and sorry for being a bit off-topic, since I'll not expound on Python, especially not `random.choice()` here), you start from a "primitive", i.e. some [random variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable) that can be generated readily, using various [pseudo-random number generators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator).

Let's suppose that this primitive is the "uniform distibution on unit interval [0, 1]", and we denote this by X. [1]

What you need is a [Bernoulli distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_distribution) with p = 0.6, i.e. among the two choices, one should be assigned probability 0.6, which implies the other given 0.4

There's a simple method, called the [acceptance-rejection method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rejection_sampling) for this.  It is as simple as follows:

```
Generate a value x of X using the "primitive" PRNG;
Test whether this x is lower than 0.6:
    If it is, output "bus"
    Otherwise, output "bike"
End
```

This is an elementary example of the wide class of rejection methods.  It is left as an exercise to see how this is related to (or in contrast with) the other answers suggested in this post (hint: how are they related to [direct transformation method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling)?).

[1] By the way, this can be done in Python by `random.random()`.

---

Feel free to mod down for off-topic ;)

Answer (score -1):

```
import random

l = ['bus', 'bus', 'bus', 'bus', 'bus', 'bus', 'bike', 'bike', 'bike', 'bike']

for i in range(len(l)):
    random.shuffle(l)
    print l[0]
    l.pop(0)
```

Comment: Would you be able to explain your answer a bit for the OP and future visitors?

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others. (This post was flagged by at least one user, presumably because they thought an answer without explanation should be deleted.)